# Looking for HAML and CoffeeScript support

Tags: listings, programming, languages

I need support for [HAML](http://haml.info/) and [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) like other languages already got with the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Do you know any solutions?

Comment: I think `minted` can help you. It relies on `Pygments`, which has both `HAML` and `CoffeeScript` lexers. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to now not every language is implemented. The package [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides a special section about setting up you own syntax. However there is also the package [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) which uses the external program Pygmentize to emphasize your code.